# Should there be a chemistry format button?

Tags: feature-request, support

I believe that for each and every different website there should be a different text editor that meets the user's needs.

So for chemistry I feel like there should be a button that does the following:

1. Person clicks the item he wants to format.
2. The button automatically does this: `$\ce{"Person's text"}$`.
3. There are two types, one that does the inline formatting: `$\ce{"text"}$` & one that does break-line: `$$\ce{"text"}$$`.

I know that this might be a lazy way of doing things but I believe that it will promote more users to format their posts more efficiently thereby improving the look of Chemistry StackExchange as a whole.

So should we do this?

Comment: Such a button has been created by @MannishEarth, [see here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70/mathjax-formatting-buttons-for-you).  I use IE since I do a lot of VBA-web interaction from Excel and the button doesn't work in IE.  You can use programs like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create your own script and then everytime you click a certain keyboard key, you can insert the scripted text into your whatever you are working on.

Comment: I mean it should be actively enabled for everyone, can moderators edit text editors?

Comment: And as we talk about graduation, I expect it to be at least considered: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/493/4945

Answer (score 2):

I see your point and therefore didn't downvote the question, but I disagree with the suggestion.

The button solution, which only embeds a string in `$\ce{` `}$` isn't flexible enough!

#### When will the button work?

It only cover the most simple cases, such as $\ce{CCl4}$!

Btw, it is very unfortunate that `$...$` ($\TeX$ shorthand) instead of the recommended $\LaTeX$ shorthand `\(...\)` is supported in MathJax for the inline math mode, while the display mode can be triggered using `$$...$$` and `\[...\]`. *Note that additional backslashes are apparently needed in MathJax!*

#### When will it fail?

1. In expressions where additional curly brackets are necessary, such as in  $\ce{^{235}U}$ or $\ce{PO4^{3-}}$.
2. In cases where **alignment** of several chemical equations is wanted. Usually, `\cee{...}` rather than `\ce{...}` is needed then.

\begin{align*}
\cee{ A + B &<=> C + D}\\
\cee{ C &<=> E + F}\\
\cee{ A + F &<<=> G}\\
\end{align*}
  3. In cases where text, greek symbols or chemical formula have to be typeset above or below reaction arrows.

\[\ce{(Ar)3C-CN <=>[h\nu][\Delta] (Ar)3C+ + CN-} \]

4. In all cases where math mode without the `mhchem` options is needed. Think thermodynamics or physical chemistry in general.

\[\Delta 2\theta = \frac{K\lambda}{L\cos\theta_0}\]

You will find lots of examples of interesting questions and excellent answers from different people where a lot of well-written $\LaTeX$ was used. Here are just seven examples in which a button solution would not have helped:

- [Schrödinger equation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14385/schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-and-wave-function)
- [Stern-Volmer equation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27203/stern-volmer-plot-and-calculating-rate-constant-for-quenching-kq)
- [Formula of entropy change](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24518/formula-of-entropy-change)
- [Boltzmann statistics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14617/how-to-obtain-product-ratio-from-energy-differences-via-boltzmann-statistics)
- [Thermodynamics problems](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7840/thermodynamics-problems/7844#7844)
- [The difference between heat of reaction at constant pressure and that at constant volume](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15644/the-difference-between-heat-of-reaction-at-constant-pressure-and-that-at-constan)
- [Derivation of relationship between Gibbs free energy and electrochemical cell potential](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6826/derivation-of-relationship-between-gibbs-free-energy-and-electrochemical-cell-po)

In summary, I think that the simple button solution only caters (understandable) laziness but keeps users from experiencing the benefits of using $\LaTeX$ in scientific writing. (And I haven't even mentioned how good it works with version-control systems, such as `svn` or `git` in collaborative writing :D)

Comment: By the way, the expressions $\ce{^235U}$ (\$\ce{^235U}\$) and $\ce{PO4^3-}$ (\$\ce{PO4^3-}\$) do not need additional braces (curly brackets). In particular, in order to avoid a wrong space between $3$ and $-$, you even should not use additional braces for $\ce{PO4^3-}$.

Comment: I'd also like to note that `\cee` does not work in MathJax-mhchem anymore (tested as of 29 Sept '16) and additionally has been deprecated since [version 4.0](ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf) of $\TeX$-mhchem. Apparently one can now use `\ce` directly, although it does seem to have a minor spacing issue (the space before the arrow seems too small).